# Join tables on two databases with two user accounts from mysql command line

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have two databases on a database server, each accessible only with a dedicated user account.

The user account for one database has no access to the other database, and vice versa.

How can I perform a join between two tables in these two databases using appropriate credentials for each?

I am using the mysql command-line tool.

Comment: You are out of luck here. You could use a federated storage engine in your machine, or implement join in application code.

Comment: Create a third user with rights on both databases and use the database name as the prefix to the table names when joining